# I am sorting data on database but webpage doesn't take effect

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

I tried to sort/order data on database. I used this command:

```
SELECT * FROM `estates`  
ORDER BY `estates`.`price`  ASC
```

It take effect on database order. But on webpage it doesn't. How can I make it take effect on webpage too? Any idea? Thank you.

By the way I am using Laravel, 
and retriving data from database with MVC
If you need to check to my page structure here it is:

```
<table cellspacing='0'> <!-- cellspacing='0' is important, must stay -->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="150px">会社名</th>
      <th width="150px">物件名</th>
      <th width="250px">住所</th>
      <th width="150px">販売価格</th>
      <th width="100px">総戸数</th>
      <th width="150px">専有面積</th>
      <th width="100px">間取り</th>
      <th width="100px">バルコニー面積</th>
      <th width="100px">竣工時期</th>
      <th width="100px">入居時期</th>
    </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
   @foreach($estates as $estate)
    <tr class="even">
      <td>{{$estate->company_name}}</td>
    <td><a href="{{json_decode($estate->link)}}" target="_blank">{{$estate->name}}</a><br/></td>
      <td>{{$estate->address}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->price}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->hows_old}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->extend}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->rooms}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->balcon_m2}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->old}}</td>
      <td>{{$estate->entery}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the controller:

```
public function sumos()
{

    $estates = Estates::get(); 
    //test

    $data['estates'] = $estates; 
    return view('welcome', $data); 

}
```

Comment: Try clearing the cache.

Comment: My browser? or laravel or database :)

Comment: I guess you are using sorting mehod in js like datatable ?

Comment: can you post your controller action method

Comment: I insert the question my controller, check it out. @TsaiKoga

Comment: ```Estates::get();```  not ```Estates::orderBy('price')->get();```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `orderBy`

```
Estates::orderBy('price')->get();
```